# Is it possible to use Emgu CV 3.0 to open a live stream with rstp protocol with ffmpeg h264

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ffmpeg, h.264, emgucv

Is it possible to use this code in capturing a video stream from an ip camera?

`Capture cap = new Capture("rtsp://192.168.42.1:554/live");
imageBox1.Image = cap.QueryFrame();`

because my image box is displaying nothing but when i tried viewing it to VLC Media Player the ip address worked. Please help.

I also tried it with VLCPlugin v2 instead of using imageBox and the ip address still work..

I also tried it with iSpy and it worked under ffmpeg(h264), maybe the problem is there? I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2010, Emgu CV 3.x. and I'm using Please help. Been working on this for long now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 cap.ImageGrabbed += VideoCapture_ImageGrabbed;
 cap.Start();
```

then:

```
private void VideoCapture_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Mat frame = new Mat();
    cap.Retrieve(frame);
}
```